# Getting no data from query. PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, so my problem is that this code returns nothing, atleast it doesn't print anything.
The only thing that seems to work is $user_email wich does print the users email.

Code:

```
        $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT u.username, g.color, g.name FROM `user` u JOIN `group` g ON g.id = u.id WHERE u.email = :email");

        $query->bindParam(':email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();

        $row = $query->fetch();
        $user_username = $row['username'];
        $group_color = $row['color'];
        $group_name = $row['name'];
        print "Values: ".$row['username']." | ".$row['name']." <br>";
```

The "user" table contains 7 different keys:

id (bigint, primary key, auto_increment), group (int), email (varchar), password (varchar), username(varchar), name (varchar), verified (int).

The "group" table contains 3 different keys:

id (bigint, primary key, auto_increment), color (varchar), name (varchar).

That's all there is inside the tables.

Comment: i believes that `u JOIN group g ON g.id = u.id WHERE` this line should be `u JOIN group g ON g.id = u.group_id WHERE` you might be join table with wrong column.

Comment: Yeah, but even if i separate so that `user` gets it's own values, it still doesn't give me anything.

Comment: When you did a test query at phpadmin what were the query results? (I'm trying to separate PDO stuff from potential query issues...)

Comment: Okay so i did what you asked, and i had to add " where the email is to make it work. Is that relevant?

Comment: Try simply querying for *SELECT u.username, g.color, g.name FROM `user` u JOIN `group` g ON g.id = u.id* in phpMyAdmin. I'm with Dipesh in believing it's a query issue. Can you edit your question with the table details for `user` and `group`?

Comment: Okay when i tried doing that it worked, but didn't return anything.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.. select the table you are interested it, then select the SQL tab, past the raw query in there. Hit the go button.  Simple way to verify your SQL stuff is straight.

Comment: Added the table contents to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the query should be

```
SELECT u.username, g.color, g.name
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN `group` g
    ON u.`group` = g.id
WHERE u.email = :email
```

Also, as `user.group` appears to be a foreign key for `group.id`, it should also be a `bigint`, not `int` (foreign keys should be the same type as their target primary key).

#### Also...

`group` is a terrible name for both a table and column. Try to steer clear of [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). I'd go with `user_group` for the table and `group_id` for the column.

Comment: It depends on the engine being used. MyISAM has no such constraint as Foreign Key, and hence, doesn't need both columns to be exact duplicates.

Comment: inner joint 'group' g on u.id = g.id...?  if you do mean u.group = g.id, how can a bigint ever = an int?

Comment: @hjpotter92 even if you're not using real foreign keys (just implied ones), the columns should match. Otherwise, you're going to run into a situation where you cannot insert a value into the smaller column

Comment: @zipzit That's why I made the note about the different data types. They can match up to the upper bounds of `int` which is 2147483647 (signed) or 4294967295 (unsigned).